# How do I eliminate decimal and characters after?

Tags: regex

I need to eliminate storage of decimals and 3 trailing characters using regular expressions and can't figure it out.

Some account numbers are `1234.001` and others are `5.000`.

I only need to include any positive whole numbers, whether 1 or 4 characters in length.

I'm currently using

```
[0-9]{1,4}$
```

and it stores the entire string. I have also tried

```
[0-9\-]{1,4}$
```

but, it doesn't eliminate the decimal and characters after.

Comment: Maybe `^[0-9]{1,4}$`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match 1 or 4 digits you could use an alternation. To keep the digits you could capture them in a group and match the trailing dot and 3 digits.

In the replacement use capture group 1 which is either 1 digits or 4 digits.

You might use word boundaries `\b` to prevent the match being part of a larger word.

```
\b(\d{4}|\d)\.\d{3}\b
```

- `\b` word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d{4}|\d` Match either 4 digits or a single digit
- `)` Close group
- `\.\d{3}` Match a dot and 3 digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOn8qQ/1)